# A Fourier Series Matlab code

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, continuous-fourier

I have created this code in order to calculate and sketch the Fourier Coefficients A0 ,An ,and Bn without using Fourier Series command  but,unfortunately the plots results did not look like a  Fourier Series. if someone please guide me to solve this problem.
thank you

*I identified all the terms that i am going to use in this project*

```
T=1; %Time Period 
wo=2*pi/T;
a0=0;% coefficient 
A0=0;% coefficient
a1=0;% coefficient
A1=0;% coefficient
a2=0;% coefficient
A2=0;% coefficient
a3=0;% coefficient
A3=0;% coefficient
a4=0;% coefficient
A4=0;% coefficient
a5=0;% coefficient
A5=0;% coefficient
a6=0;% coefficient
A6=0;% coefficient
a7=0;% coefficient
B7=0;% coefficient
b1=0;% coefficient
B1=0;% coefficient
b2=0;% coefficient
B2=0;% coefficient
b3=0;% coefficient
B3=0;% coefficient
b4=0;% coefficient
B4=0;% coefficient
b5=0;% coefficient
B5=0;% coefficient
b6=0;% coefficient
B6=0;% coefficient
b7=0;% coefficient
B7=0;% coefficient
```

in this step. i want to calculate the values of my function and store them in a Matrix.

```
x=0:0.1:T; % x is the time axis
k=1:T/0.1+1;
funcation=x;
F(k)=funcation;
for x=0:0.1:T;
  k=1:T/0.1+1;
  a0=F(k)+a0;
end
A0=0.1*a0/T;
for x=0:0.1:T;
  k=1:T/0.1+1;
  b1=F(k).*sin(1.*wo.*x)+b1;
  b2=F(k).*sin(2.*wo.*x)+b2;
  b3=F(k).*sin(3.*wo.*x)+b3;
  b4=F(k).*sin(4.*wo.*x)+b4;
  b5=F(k).*sin(5.*wo.*x)+b5;
  b6=F(k).*sin(6.*wo.*x)+b6;
  b7=F(k).*sin(7.*wo.*x)+b7;
end
for x=0:0.1:T;
  B1=0.1.*2.*b1./T.*sin(1.*wo.*x);
  B2=0.1.*2.*b2./T.*sin(2.*wo.*x);
  B3=0.1.*2.*b3./T.*sin(3.*wo.*x);
  B4=0.1.*2.*b4./T.*sin(4.*wo.*x);
  B5=0.1.*2.*b5./T.*sin(5.*wo.*x);
  B6=0.1.*2.*b6./T.*sin(6.*wo.*x);
  B7=0.1.*2.*b7./T.*sin(7.*wo.*x);
end
bq=B1+B2+B3+B4+B5+B6+B7;

for x=0:0.1:T;
  k=1:T/0.1+1;
  a1=F(k).*cos(1.*wo.*x)+a1;
  a2=F(k).*cos(2.*wo.*x)+a2;
  a3=F(k).*cos(3.*wo.*x)+a3;
  a4=F(k).*cos(4.*wo.*x)+a4;
  a5=F(k).*cos(5.*wo.*x)+a5;
  a6=F(k).*cos(6.*wo.*x)+a6;
  a7=F(k).*cos(7.*wo.*x)+a7;
end
for x=0:0.1:T;
  A1=0.1.*2.*a1./T.*cos(1.*wo.*x);
  A2=0.1.*2.*a2./T.*cos(2.*wo.*x);
  A3=0.1.*2.*a3./T.*cos(3.*wo.*x);
  A4=0.1.*2.*a4./T.*cos(4.*wo.*x);
  A5=0.1.*2.*a5./T.*cos(5.*wo.*x);
  A6=0.1.*2.*a6./T.*cos(6.*wo.*x);
  A7=0.1.*2.*a7./T.*cos(7.*wo.*x);
end
aq=A1+A2+A3+A4+A5+A6+A7;

FQ=bq+aq+A0;
plot(F(k))
figure
plot(FQ)
```

Comment: Well, for one, you assign different values repeatedly to `B1` et al. That is probably a bug? Idem with `A1` et al. But you would do well in avoiding 90% of the variables  you define. It would make it a lot easier to understand the math if there were fewer variables. One more thing: `A1=0.01...`, all the other lines in that block use 0.1, not 0.01. How about using a constant to store 0.1?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in defining `for` loops in your script.
You shouldn't insert a semicolon `;` at the end of `for` expression. 
Instead of:
`for x=0:0.1:T;` 
you should omit `;` and write it like:
`for x=0:0.1:T`

then the plots work fine and both plots will be identical. As your function here is y=x, it would be a 45 degree line.